# Why are my Perl threads stuck in an infinite loop? (Thread::Queue)

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue, infinite-loop

I am using [`Thread::Queue`](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread::Queue) to push an array onto a queue and process each element of it using threads. Below is a simplified version of my program to demonstrate what is happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

# Define queue
my $QUEUE :shared = new Thread::Queue();

# Define values
my @values = qw(string1 string2 string3);

# Enqueue values
$QUEUE->enqueue(@values);

# Get thread limit
my $QUEUE_SIZE   = $QUEUE->pending();
my $thread_limit = $QUEUE_SIZE;

# Create threads
for my $i (1 .. $thread_limit) {
    my $thread = threads->create(\&work);
}

# Join threads
my $i = 0;
for my $thread (threads->list()) {
    $thread->join();
}

print "COMPLETE\n";

# Thread work function
sub work {
    while (my $value = $QUEUE->dequeue()) {
        print "VALUE: $value\n";
        sleep(5);
        print "Finished sleeping\n";
    }
    print "Got out of loop\n";
}
```

When I run this code I get the following output and then it just hangs forever:

```
VALUE: string1
VALUE: string2
VALUE: string3
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
Finished sleeping
```

Once the queue reaches its end, the while loop should break and the script should continue but it doesn't appear to ever get out of the loop.

Why is this getting stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you never call `$QUEUE->end()`, your threads are blocking on `dequeue()` waiting for more entries to appear.

So, ensure you do call `$QUEUE->end()` after the last call to enqueue, or before joining the threads.

Comment: Thanks @Hasturkun! I literally jussssst realized that right before you posted your answer *face palm*.  Although it was just a dumb mistake I'll leave this question up in case some other poor sap runs into the same situation.

Comment: Note: `->end` requires T::Q version 3.01+